# How to Remove Comment and Author Icons from Wordpress Blog Post Page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to remove the icons shown in the wp site image below: 
[image: Want to Remove the marked Author Icon and Comment Count]

Here is Another Image where I wishto remove the author icon -

[image: Want to Remove the 'Posted by' here]

Comment: Inspect the element in dev console. Identify the css responsible for the icon and over ride the same via your custom css.

Comment: it mainly depend on theme, but you can check function from archive.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using css. Inspect the html document and identify the classes affect the author's details section. Eg.

```
.suspect-class{
    display: none;
}
```

One option is to modify the `archive.php`. If the theme you're working from is paid, I suggest you go in the direction of building a child theme where you can basically overwrite/edit the parent theme's design etc.